# Question about exception guarantees for custom operator=

Tags: c++, exception, c++20, assignment-operator

I have a class used to work with disk data consisting of an `enum class` and `vector<char>` sized based on the enum. The enum is an invariant for each object and is therefor const with two possible values. Because it's an invariant, one must write a `operator=` member function. My standard approach is this:

```
A& operator=(const A& rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        std::destroy_at(this);
        std::construct_at(this, rhs);
    };
    return *this;
};
```

This is does not fulfill the strict exception guarantee and it isn't clear to me if it even meets the minimal guarantee.

The approach I'm using both protects against self assignment and provides strict exception guarantees but is somewhat awkward, requires code tailored to the class and only works with simple invariants that are trivially destructable and standard containers that have specialized `swap()` methods. Fortunately, these restrictions apply to most of my use cases.

Is there some generalization like copy and swap that works with classes like these?

**Example code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

enum class Mode { data_sector, data_fat };
struct DiskBuf {
    const Mode mode;
    std::vector<char> buf;
    explicit DiskBuf(Mode mode) : mode(mode), buf(mode==Mode::data_sector ? 2048 : 8192) {}
    DiskBuf operator=(const DiskBuf& rhs) {
        auto buf_tmp = rhs.buf; // this may throw but maintains strict exception guarantee
        this->buf.swap(buf_tmp);
        std::construct_at(&this->mode, rhs.mode);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DiskBuf a{Mode::data_sector}, b{Mode::data_fat};
    std::cout << "a.mode: " << (int)a.mode << ", a.buf.size(): " << a.buf.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "b.mode: " << (int)b.mode << ", b.buf.size(): " << b.buf.size() << '\n';
    a = b;
    std::cout << "After a=b\n";
    std::cout << "a.mode: " << (int)a.mode << ", a.buf.size(): " << a.buf.size() << '\n';
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/E9TovTvEW)

Comment: `const` data members generally suck. Consider making it a private non-const member with a getter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm a big fan of const as much as possible. Until c++20 you couldn't do this for member variables w/o severe restrictions but now you can. So I do where it's not too onerous. I like to have the compiler catch bugs at compile time.

Comment: `mode` isn't constant, though. You're trying to change it in `operator=`, so it shouldn't be marked `const`, right? Or if you really want it `const`, I'd expect assignment to be disabled.

Comment: @JohnKugelman mode is an invariant for each object. It can differ from one object to the next but as an invariant I like to make it a const. That automatically requires one to write an assignment operator to make it reasonably useful like in a vector. This is all perfectly legal. Prior to c++ it wasn't practical because you couldn't modify a const in a class. But now you can.

Comment: Do you really want buffers to be copied, though? It looks like you're storing 2KB or 8KB of data in them, making copying relatively expensive. It seems like a performance footgun to have a vector of them. My inclination would be to disable assignment and have users access them via smart pointers if they want copying. Copying pointers is cheap.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The `swap()` specialization swaps the guts. No copy. An initial copy is required for the assignment just as it would would were the default  mode not const.

Comment: `auto buf_tmp = rhs.buf;` is a copy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244728/discussion-between-john-kugelman-and-doug).

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, of course. Just as a copy is made with the defaulted assignment operator were mode not const. I left off the move operators which are needed for efficient operation in, for instance, vectors of the class. Similar code but w/o the copy.

Comment: I don't get it. You say "mode is an invariant for each object." But then the assignment operator changes it: In your example, the mode of `a` is initially `data_sector` and then after the assignment, the mode of `a` is `data_fat`. The mode of `a` varied. It's not an invariant.

Comment: @RaymondChen It's an invariant in each object. Once the object's lifetime starts it's invariant. That doesn't prevent  copying one object to another of the same class which ends the lifetime of the old object and replaces it with the new one.

Comment: This definition of "lifetime" is likely to confuse developers who are using your classes. From a typical developer's point of view, the assignment `a = b` does not destroy `a`, and then create a brand new object also called `a`. It assigns `b` to `a`. The `a` is still alive; it just got a new value assigned to it. People who see that `mode` is `const` will assume that the value does not change between `a`'s construction and destruction.

Comment: @RaymondChen  I think const members are so rare (they are nearly universally discouraged if not banned) that I think the typical developer doesn't think about them at all. They can result in counterintuitive behavior and were impossible to use in any normal sense. For good reason. Changing them was UB.  So one gets crazy things like this: [Nutty example of sorting with const as required to avoid UB prior to c++20](https://godbolt.org/z/e5f136GMd)

Comment: @RaymondChen but now with c++20 one can get [something rational](https://godbolt.org/z/Thh93f7cE).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not undefined behavior, but it is nearly impossible to avoid undefined behavior from your code.

`const` data in C++ is **truly immutable**.  You are attempting to bypass this.  Your bypass really doesn't work; any variable, name, pointer or reference referring to the *old* object before the destroy/construct will not refer to the new object.

This causes problems at destruction time (because the variable is destroyed; this is double-destruction).

There are exceptions for "creating an object in place of an old one" that do not cause this problem, but they *explicity* exclude cases where there is an actual `const` member or object.

In practice, this is because the compiler is free to notice your `const` enum field is initialized at one spot, and *be absolutely certain* that the value never changes.  It can skip any reading of the value at any point in the future, so long as it can prove the `const` object was initialized with a specific value.

Your destroy/construct breaks this assumption.  The result is the compiler's axioms being violated, and your program could be pathologically insane.

The standard does not specify that accessing a newly constructed object in a place where an old one with `const` in it is not allowed due to the above optimization; it simply states your program is exhibiting undefined behavior.  This UB exists, however, to make such optimizations possible.

`const` fields and `const` objects have meaning to the C++ compiler.  `const` references .. don't, as you are free to `const_cast` away the `const`.  But really `const` fields and objects are not something you can work around by assinging over them.

If you want something immutable but replacable, do this:

```
struct DiskBuf;
enum class Mode { data_sector, data_fat };
struct DiskBufInternal {
  friend struct DiskBuf;
  Mode mode;
  std::vector<char> buf;
  explicit DiskBufInternal(Mode mode) :
    mode(mode),
    buf(mode==Mode::data_sector ? 2048 : 8192)
  {}
  DiskBufInternal operator=(const DiskBuf& rhs) = delete;
private:
  struct secret_token { explicit secret_token(int); };
public:
  explicit DiskBufInternal(secret_token, Mode mode, std::vector<char> b) :
    mode(mode),
    buf(std::move(b))
  {}
};
struct DiscBuf {
  std::unique_ptr<DiskBufInternal> pImpl;
  explicit DiscBuf(Mode mode):
    pImpl(std::make_unique<DiskBufInternal>(mode))
  {}
  DiscBuf& operator=(DiscBuf const& o)&{
    if (!o.pImpl) {
      pImpl = {}
      return;
    }
    pImpl = std::make_unique<DiscBufInternal>(
      DiscBufInternal::secret_token(0),
      o.pImpl->mode,
      o.pImpl->buf
    );
    return *this;
  };
```

here we keep a `unique_ptr` to our `DiscBufInternal`.

Another option is a `std::optional`, but that lacks the weak exception guarantee.  Maybe that can be gotten via a no-throw move ctor on the `DiscBufInternal`.

Comment: "in practice, this is because the compiler is free to notice your const enum field is initialized at one spot, and be absolutely certain that the value never changes." This used to be true but is no longer true as of c++20 unless the top object is const, a so called "complete const object" see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8

Comment: Compare the c++20 basic life with this c++17 which specifically cites const data members as not allowing this. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8.3